# sqlserver 2008r2 service pack incompletely applied on shared features

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed sqlserver 2008R2 service pack 3 on my instance.

The installation went through successfully but the instance still shows version number of SP1 in management studio.

When I start the patch setup again, I see that the main database features are patched correctly but that the shared features are "incompletely applied"

Can someone explain me what to do with this ?

Would a reboot help ?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xtPce9a.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/WNibJ3N.png]

Comment: I rebooted the server and it did not change the upgrade status.

Comment: Have you looked at the setup logs to see what "incompletely" means? Where are you seeing SP1 in Management Studio? If that is from @@VERSION it is likely the operating system service pack level, not SSMS.

Comment: Also, do you really need to be using such an old version of SSMS? [This new version is much better for most things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) except for managing things like legacy SSIS packages / maintenance plans.

Comment: Alright I'll give SSMS2016 a try but anyhow I always access this server remotely so the local SSMS doesn't change much.
Here is the output of @@VERSION :
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)   Jun 11 2012 16:41:53   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: So the engine you're connecting to is still SP1, not SP3. And its operating system is a version of Windows with Service Pack 1 applied. Where are you getting that SSMS is at SP1?

Comment: not sure what you're asking but here's a screenshot 
https://i.imgur.com/6K0Bl5x.png

Comment: That's not SSMS, that's the server you're connecting to. Try Help > About in SSMS.

Comment: Here's what I get from this https://i.imgur.com/xkW0GVB.png

Comment: Looks like Service Pack 3 applied to SSMS just fine. If you want to understand what "Incompletely installed" means, you're going to have to review the logs (search your computer for a folder called "Setup Bootstrap") - we can't guess.

Answer (score 1):

After running an instance repair, the correct version number is now being displayed.

The shared features are still incompletely installed but at least querying the @@version view will now return the correct patch level.